# Stacknavigator with redux without navigation prop in redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, stack-navigator

i want to use react-navigation and redux in my app but i don't want to save the navigation property in the redux states. Instead i just want to navigate like before but have the redux states as well, i saw the following approach which i implemented into my App.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => state;
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => dispatch;

// need this Higher Order Component so you can pass properties through the root stack
const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RootStack);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={Store}>
          <AppContainer />
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

but when i tried to use this approach i got the

```
"you must pass a component to the function returned by connect. instead received"
```

error.

Here is my StackNavigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import {HomeScreen} from '../screens/HomeScreen'
import {CardScreen} from '../screens/CardScreen'


const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Card: CardScreen,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null, 
        },
    }
);

export default RootStack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RootStack` is not a react component. You need to do something like this, I'd suggest moving to a separate file:

```
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <RootStack />
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer)
```

Now you can import `AppContainer` and pass it to your `App` component

Comment: i tried to do it this way and now i get the 'Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "connect(App)".' I'll update my post to the full code of App.js and my store

Comment: i think i have another problem, i will ask it in a separate question. But this is resolved now.